# MariaDB JSON_SEARCH function not working with Variable

Tags: json, mariadb

I'm trying to create a MariaDB function..!
I'm using MariaDB..!

```
SET @j = '["abc", [{"k": "10"}, "def"], {"x":"abc"}, {"y":"bcd"}]';
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@j, 'one', 'abc');
//output: 
"$[0]" //it's ok.
```

above one is working, but, I want to pass variable value in place of 'abc' in json_search function (below one):

```
SET @j = '["abc", [{"k": "10"}, "def"], {"x":"abc"}, {"y":"bcd"}]';
SET @val = (SELECT val FROM users WHERE id = 1); // abc
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@j, 'one', @val);
//output:
NULL //It's not working with variable @val
```

what's the solution?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=554ec21fac32a266a6469bf7772c81a7).

Comment: If this is your exact code, the problem is that you haven't quoted `table` in backticks i.e. `SET @val = (SELECT val FROM \`table\` WHERE id = 1);` and so `@val` has nothing in it.

Comment: i checked that dbfiddle, it works with mysql. but, I'm using mariadb. I checked dbfiddle with mariadb, It's not working.

Comment: `table` is a reserved word, see [9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T), therefore, using `table` (unqualified), it would generate an error, so I assume that it does not use `table` as a table name.

Comment: nothing about table, ok, i replaced table with users. please check that dbfiddle with mariadb, it's not working.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e99641d9ce227ddda2cdef8006f847d3).

Comment: Check [`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_ssl).

Comment: See MariaDB bug report: [MDEV-17018 :: JSON_SEARCH and User-Defined Variables](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17018).